# Is there a chart which details the major common pronunciations of Hebrew?

Tags: hebrew, product-recommendation, pronunciation

I learned how to pronounce Hebrew from the book ["Teach Yourself to Read Hebrew"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0939144115) which describes pronunciation with Sephardic vocalization. For example, *patach* and *kamatz*, according to the book, are pronounced more or less the same, and there's no difference between a *tav* with a *dagesh* and a *tav* without a *dagesh*.

After becoming very fast in reading the Sephardic pronunciation, I decided to start learning the Ashkenazic pronunciation, so I began working on pronouncing a *tav* without a *dagesh* as a *sav*. It then dawned on me that there seem to be a few other differences between the pronunciations that I wasn't aware of and am still unclear on.

Is there a chart or program available which details the major different pronunciations and their differences? I'm primarily interested in the Sephardic, Ashkenazic, Chassidic, Hungarian, and Yemenite pronunciations. Is there a resource available which can help me do this?

It's kind of a bummer to be learning about these differences this late in the game, but better late than never :)

Answer (score 4):

[An old revision of `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Hebrew_phonology#Regional_and_historical_variation`](//en.wikipedia.org/?oldid=502209428#Regional_and_historical_variation) provides much of what you want.